# URL Redirect in Wordpress

Tags: url-rewriting

I am facing problem to redirect some url in wordpress. I need to rewrite following URL:

First URL is like this: http://example.com/news/?news=2 where news=2 is the news id and I am getting this id by using $_GET['news']. I want to rewrite this above url to http://example.com/news/2/

Second URL is like this: example[dot]com/product-list/?pp=2&page=3/ and I want to rewrite it as example[dot]com/product-list/2/3/

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of rewriting, I'm using this code (haven't tested this one exactly, so may contain minor bugs):

```
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'binda_query_vars' );
function binda_query_vars( $vars ) {
    $vars[] = 'pp';
    return $vars;
}

add_action( 'generate_rewrite_rules', 'binda_rewrite_rules' );
function binda_rewrite_rules( $wp_rewrite )
{
    $wp_rewrite->rules = array(
        'news/([0-9]{1,})/([0-9]{1,})/?$' => $wp_rewrite->index . '?post_type=news' . '&pp=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index( 1 ) . '&paged=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index( 2 ),
        'news/([0-9]{1,})/?$' => $wp_rewrite->index . '?post_type=news' . '&pp=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index( 1 ),
        'product-list/([0-9]{1,})/([0-9]{1,})/?$' => $wp_rewrite->index . '?post_type=product' . '&pp=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index( 1 ) . '&paged=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index( 2 ),
        'product-list/([0-9]{1,})/?$' => $wp_rewrite->index . '?post_type=product' . '&pp=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index( 1 ),
    ) + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
```

You may need to replace post_type=news and post_type=product for appropriate post_type created in your system.

**Note** that this does not replace your permalinks in a template, you have to do that manually.